# What's the difference between these two uses of sizeof() in C?

Tags: c, memory, character, sizeof

If I do `sizeof('r')`, the character 'r' requires 4 bytes in memory. Alternatively, if I first declare a `char` variable and initialize it like so:

```
  char val = 'r';
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(val));
```

The output indicates that 'r' only requires 1 byte in memory.

Why is this so?

Comment: 'c' is the ASCII value o char c

Comment: 'r' in your example, sorry :-) 'r' e.g. is 114 in ASCII table (a integer has 4 bytes)

Comment: "The output indicates that 'r' only requires 1 byte in memory" is an incorrect conclusion.  The output indicates that `val` requires 1 byte in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the constant `'c'` is interpreted as an `int`.
If you run this:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof( (char) 'c' ) );
```

it will print `1`.

Comment: Thanks Kenney, this makes sense! I changed all the 'c' to 'r' in my examples because I realized I was inconsistent.

Comment: Oh well, all chars are the same size, aren't they ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In C literal `'c'` is called **integer** character constant and according to the C Standard:

> 10 An integer character constant has type **int**.

On the other hand, in C++ this literal is called **character** literal and according to the C++ Standard:

> An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char
>   representable in the execution character set has type **char**.

In this declaration

```
char val = 'r';
```

variable `val` is explicitly declared as having type `char`. In both the languages `sizeof( char )` is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the literal `'r'` is considered an integer and its value is its ASCII value. An `int` requires generally 4 bytes hence the output. With the second case you are explicitly declaring it as a character, hence it outputs 1.

If you try this line `printf("%d",(10+'c'));` It will print 109 as the output i.e. `(10+99)`.

Answer (score 0):

For some clarification you may want to take a look at this table.
http://goo.gl/nOa5ju (ascii table for chars)

Firstly, in C there are two types of int. 16 bit (2 byte) and 32 bit (4 byte).

A constant char in C is considered an int which relates to the character it represents on the table. The decimal value of 'c' is 99 (2 bytes per).

There you go, you got the char or in other words int value being 99 or 4 bytes.

On the other hand though the `char var = 'c';` is a 1 byte value because ASCII is represented with 8 bits (1 byte). 
table of c type sizes http://goo.gl/yhxmSF